# Read a file within an archived archive (without extracting)

Tags: python, zip, archive

What I am trying to do is to read a file located in an archived archive as shown below:
[I want to access a "document.txt" file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5IxL.png)

Code 1:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("archive.zip", mode="r") as archive:
   with zipfile.ZipFile("archive2.zip", mode="r") as archive2:
      text = archive2.read("document.txt")
      print(text) #FileNotFountError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'archive2.zip'
```

Code 2:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("archive.zip/archive2.zip", mode="r") as archive:
   text = archive.read("document.txt")
   print(text) #FileNotFountError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'archive.zip/archive2.zip'
```

None of the above works. How can I read a "document.txt" file that is located in an "archive2.zip", which in turn is located in an "archive.zip" file without extracting anything? Thank you very much.

[archive.zip file for your reference](https://ufile.io/p9tdz5l8)

Answer (score 0):

You need to open first then read it.
Ex:-

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("archive.zip/archive2.zip", mode="r") as archive:
   text = archive.open("document.txt").read().decode()
   print(text)
```

Comment: This one gives an error: ```FileNotFountError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'archive.zip/archive2.zip'```

Comment: it means that there are no files with name document.txt inside zip file. check it if it is there,  using [z.filename for z in archive.filelist]

Comment: you can use dir(<object name> ) to see the methods of the object.

Comment: "document.txt" is indeed within "archive2.zip", and "archive2.zip" is within "archive.zip file". I have added the ZIP file to the post for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to open `archive.zip`, then read the raw `archive2.zip` file and finally read the document within that zip file.

```py
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile(r"archive.zip", "r") as archive:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(archive.open(r"archive/archive2.zip", "r")) as archive2:
        doc = archive2.open("archive2/document.txt")
        content = doc.readlines()
        print(content)
```

Comment: This one gives an error:

```KeyError: "There is no item named 'archive/archive2.zip' in the archive"```

Comment: Could you check the output of `print(archive.namelist())` ? And archive2?

Comment: Everything is as described in the post. I have also added the archive.zip file for your reference.

Comment: Could you replace the first line: `r"archive.zip"` with the absolute path to your zip file?